# spawn play ENOENT NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Estou tentando usar uma biblioteca chamada **troubadour**:

```
const Troubadour = require('troubadour');
const troubadour = new Troubadour('sox');

app.get('/playmusics', function(req, res){

    troubadour.on('start', () => {
      // Do something here when the audio starts playing
      console.log('Começou');
    });

    troubadour.on('end', () => {
      // Do something here when the audio finishes playing
      console.log('Finalizado');
    });

    troubadour.play(__dirname+'/assets/musics/infiel.mp3');

    troubadour.on('error', (error) => {
      // Do something here to handle the errors
      console.log('Erro :( : ', error);
    });
});
```

Mas quando entro na URL `/playmusics` o servidor cai e me retorna o erro no terminal:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn play ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Não sei o que pode ser, pois já tentei de várias formas e nada funciona.

Comment: Já tentou isolar o erro para descobrir o que causa ele? Se você comentar a linha troubadour.play(__dirname+'/assets/musics/infiel.mp3'); o erro permanece?

Comment: @André quando retiro não da nenhum erro, a página no navegador fica como se tivesse só carregando, mas não exibe nenhum erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei, essa biblioteca(Troubadour) precisa de um player de áudio instalado no seu sistema, você pode conferir a lista de players suportados nessa página: https://github.com/jaredpetersen/troubadour/blob/master/lib/supportedAudioPlayers.json

No seu caso, você está usando o sox (`const troubadour = new Troubadour('sox');`). Certifique-se que você tem ele instalado no seu sistema e configurado como pede o link acima que eu lhe enviei, o processo precisa ter o nome de *play* e o comando também.

Esse erro pode ocorrer pois o Node está tentando executar o sox, porém ele não está instalado no sistema.

Comment: Instalei o SOX e agora não deu mais erro, o único problema agora é que ele não abre o áudio parece. Ele aparece a mensagem `Começou' e em seguida já o 'Finalizado' e não executa o áudio, mas creio que ai já é outra coisa do plugin

Comment: O comando e o processo do sox estão como play? Definiu ele nas variáveis de ambiente do sistema?

Comment: funcionou agora, o problema que não estava executando é porque o áudio tem que ser em WAV :). Obrigado